# how to connect node js to quickbooks v3 REST API

Tags: node.js, oauth, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to connect to Intuits v3 REST api, using node.js. I am using SuperAgent and superagent-oauth to make the requests. I generated the access tokens using Intuits Oauth playground. But I keep getting "ApplicationAuthenticationFailed; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401"

This is what I am using.

```
var  OAuth = require('oauth')
,request = require('superagent');
require('superagent-oauth')(request);
var oauth = new OAuth.OAuth('','', consumerKey, consumerSecret, '1.0.A', null, 'HMAC-SHA1')  

request.get("https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/672198300/customer/102")
.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
.accept('json')
.sign(oauth,accessToken,accessTokenSecret )
.end(function (err, res) {
    console.log(res.text)
})
```

and here is the response

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <IntuitResponse time="2014-06-14T18:33:49.228-07:00" xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
<Fault type="AUTHENTICATION">
    <Error code="3200">
        <Message>message=ApplicationAuthenticationFailed; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401</Message>
    </Error>
</Fault>
```

Can anyone shed any light on what is happening?

Comment: Please use correct Content-Type: application/json. I've not tried these calls using node. So, not sure if Content-Type is the only issue here. Thanks

Comment: according to SuperAgent docs, accept('application/json') is a valid way to set the accept. http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#setting-accept.  
have I missed something?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the node.js [client library](https://github.com/mcohen01/node-quickbooks)

Like most other clients, that would save you from manually building http requests. Just provide the application credentials and the individual user credentials and you can simply call methods on a Javascript object. All of the REST endpoints have corresponding methods on the QuickBooks object, which follows node.js convention and takes an optional callback as the last argument.

Comment: Michael, great work btw, I don't see your DSL on top of the Quickbooks API matching the new Payments API given by Quickbooks, nor does it follow the charge capture lifecycle described in the API. As a result I've had to do the same as OP and use `request` to make the requests against the api.

Answer (score 2):

SOlVED!

I used [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) to create the request. And it worked. Then I checked the oAuth header Postman had generated against the one I was generating with node ( I used requestBin to see the header of my request ).  I discovered that the only real difference was that I was using "1.0A" as the version.  Changing that to "1.0" worked!

```
var oauth = new OAuth.OAuth('','', consumerKey, consumerSecret, '1.0', null, 'HMAC-SHA1')
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have anything for ou in node.js but can provide you with raw request and response for the calls. Compare your raw requests against this. The signature should be double encoded.
Get Request token call-

GET https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token?oauth_callback=oob&oauth_nonce=34562646-ab97-46e1-9aa7-f814d83ef9d1&oauth_consumer_key=qyprd7I5WvVgWDFnPoiBh1ejZn&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1392306961&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=0EtvSnzsuumeyib2fiEcnSyu8%3D HTTP/1.1
Host: oauth.intuit.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 13 Feb 2014 15:56:03 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 150
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain

oauth_token_secret=dXhHHMS1EfdrQ32UabOMscIRWt5bLJNX3ZKljjBc&oauth_callback_confirmed=true&oauth_token=qyprdbwXdWrAt0xM2NgkLlJ79yCp4I2SmDg7tahDBPjA6Wti

Get Access Token-

GET https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_access_token?oauth_verifier=b4skra3&oauth_token=qyprde5fvI7WNOQjTKYLDzTVxJ2dLPTgQEQSPlDVGxEy9wZX&oauth_nonce=f20a5a4b-3635-40a8-92cf-697dfdb07b9d&oauth_consumer_key=qyprd7I5WvVgJZUvWDFnPoiBh1ejZn&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1392397399&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=gEVHttlM8IBAAkmi1dSNJgkKGsI%3D HTTP/1.1
Host: oauth.intuit.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 14 Feb 2014 17:03:20 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 120
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain

oauth_token_secret=474gtp6xsFzNJ1EhrrjiHrTH96xXieaRLinjPomA&oauth_token=qyprdNIpWn2oYPupMpeH8Byf9Bhun5rPpIZZtTbNsPyFtbT4

Comment: Thanks. I already have the accessToken, which I got by going to Intuits oAuth console. My Signature is double encoded, though, and every thing else looks the same.

I suspect, I am missing something quite basic here. But I have no clue what it is.

Comment: Did you add the Content-Type: text/plain ?

Comment: I just tried it. I set the request Content-Type to "text/plain", and the accept to 'json'.  Still no good.